# NHibernate - How to handle critical transaction in ASP.NET MVC action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, transactions, optimistic-locking, pessimistic-locking

I have an action that handle a critical transaction and I am not sure what would be the best way to handle the transaction.

Here is a simplified example of what I would need to do:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult BeginOrderProcess(Guid orderKey)
{
    // Not sure what isolation level I sould use here to start with...
    IsolationLevel isolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted;
    using(new TransactionScope(isolationLevel)){

        // Retreive the order
        var order = GetExistingOrder(orderKey);

        // Validate that the order can be processed
        var validationResult = ValidateOrder(order);

        if (!validationResult.Successful)
        {
            // Order cannot be processed, returning
            return View("ErrorOpeningOrder");
        }

        // Important stuff going on here, but I must be sure it 
        // will never be called twice for the same order
        BeginOrderProcess(order);

        return View("OrderedProcessedSuccessfully");
    }
}
```

First thing I would ask is: in this kind of operation, where we can have multiple requests at the same time for the same order (i.e.:quick requests from browser for same order), should I use pessimistic locking to really ensure one transaction at the time or there is a way to make sure `BeginOrderProcess` would never be called twice with two concurrent requests for the same order almost at the same time with optimistic locking (considering that it would probably be faster)?

Second thing: Am I doing it completely the wrong way and there is a better way to handle cases like this? In other words, how should I handle this? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after some research, I think I've found what I wanted.

For a case like this, it would be overkill to use pessimistic lock with nhibernate (by using `session.Lock(order)`)

I've opted for optimistic lock simply because I didn't know how to use it before.

Here's what the code should look like:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult BeginOrderProcess(Guid orderKey)
{
    // I confirm, here I really want ReadCommit since I need optimistic lock
    IsolationLevel isolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted;
    using(var tx = new TransactionScope(isolationLevel)){

        // Retreive the order
        var order = GetExistingOrder(orderKey);

        // Validate that the order can be processed
        var validationResult = ValidateOrder(order);

        if (!validationResult.Successful)
        {
            // Order cannot be processed, returning
            return View("ErrorOpeningOrder");
        }

        // Important stuff going on here, but I must be sure it 
        // will never be called twice for the same order
        BeginOrderProcess(order);

        // The main difference is here
        // I need to do an explicit commit here to catch the stale object exception
        // and handle it properly. Before that, 
        // I was handling the commit in the dispose of my TransactionScope
        // Since my transaction scope is in ReadCommit, no one but this request 
        // should be able to read the modified data whatever the changes are
        try{
            try{
                tx.Commit();
            }catch(Exception){
                tx.RollBack();
                throw;
            }            
        }catch(StaleObjectStateException){
            return View("OrderIsCurrentlyBeeingProcessedBySomeoneElse");
        }

        return View("OrderedProcessedSuccessfully");
    }
}
```

As my comment shows, the main difference is that I handle my commit manually and then handle the exception as it would. With this implementation, I wont worry about blocking other users requests and I can handle the exception as I need.

I am using fluent nhibernate and I've configured my entities to use version in my mappings:

```
OptimisticLock.Version();

Version(x => x.Version)
.Column("EntityVersion")
.Generated.Never()
.Default(0)
.UnsavedValue("null");
```

With this, when I am doing my commit, NHibernate will look at the version and throw a `StaleObjectStateException` if the commit doesn't match the right version.

Happy NHibernating :)